# PHP string to array conversion

Tags: php, arrays

I've got a string `1,2,3,4,5`

I convert it to a PHP array: `$arr = explode(',', $myString);`

Then I want to echo them from my new array:

```
foreach ($arr as $value) {
     echo $value;
}
```

The problem - for some reason it adds a **blank space** at the start of my array! So instead of `1` for instance, our value is `1` with a space infront of it.

Why is this happening and how could I get rid of it?

Comment: Does your string have a space at the start? Try `$arr = explode(',', trim($myString));`

Answer (score 4):

This could happen if your string contains whitespace at the beginning or end. The `explode()` function will just split the string on the given delimiter and won't magically take care of the whitespace. You can use [`array_map()`](http://php.net/array_map) to trim the whitespace from all array elements:

```
$arr = explode(',', $myString);
$arr = array_map('trim', $arr);
```

Or you could replace the whitespace before using `explode()` using a regular expression (or `str_replace()`, depending on the situation):

```
$myString = ' 1,2,3,4,5 ';
$myString = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $myString);
```

This will strip out all the whitespace and the string would contain only the numbers and commas (assuming that is what you want).

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that there is whitespace at the beginning of the string.

Anyway, you can use [`trim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php):

```
foreach ($arr as $value) 
{
     echo trim($value);
}
```

Or you can use it at the explode point:

```
$arr = explode(',', trim($myString));
```

Comment: Just a note. The `foreach` loop in your code wouldn't actually modify the value. You need to pass `$value` by reference in order to do that.

Comment: Not sure I understand your comment? The `trim()` is inside the loop, right after the `echo`...

Comment: In the first part of your answer, you aren't actually modifying the `$arr` -- just printing the trimmed value. With this code, you'll be passing the same old string to `explode()` function and the results would be same as before.

Comment: Yes, I know... That's why the `trim()` is inside the loop.